# How to Sort two field (date and boolean) comparator in java

Tags: java

I want sort date and order by two boolean, but result is wrong.
First sort by date, and if boolean1 and boolean 2 is false priority is hight, next: boolean 2 is true

```
List<Project> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Project(false, false, new Date("1/1/2019"), "Jet" , "1"));
list.add(new Project(true, false, new Date("1/1/2019"), "Sang", "2"));
list.add(new Project(false, false, new Date("1/1/2019"), "Dung", "1"));
list.add(new Project(false, true, new Date("1/1/2020"), "Long", "1"));
list.add(new Project(true, false, new Date("1/1/2020"), "Nguyen", "3"));
list.add(new Project(true, false, new Date("1/1/2020"), "Khang", "2"));

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Project>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Project o1, Project o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int result = o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
        if (result != 0) return result;
        boolean o1boolean1 = o1.boolean1;
        boolean o1boolean2 = o1.boolean2;
        boolean o2boolean1 = o2.boolean1;
        boolean o2boolean2 = o2.boolean2;
        result = Boolean.compare((!o1boolean1 && !o1boolean2), (!o2boolean1 && !o2boolean2));
        if (result != 0) {
            return result;
        }
        return Boolean.compare(o1boolean2, o2boolean2);
    }
});

for(Project pp : list) {
    System.out.println(pp.name);
}
```

I wan result :Jet, Dung, Sang, Long, Nguyen, Khang
Please help me.

Comment: Please provide boolean pairs in expected order. Lets say we have (B1, B2) pairs like (T, T), (T, F), (F, T), (F, F), how should they be ordered?

Comment: I want (F,F), (F, T), boolean 1 and boolean 2 nerver true at the same time

Comment: What about (F,T) vs (T,F) are these considered as equal or is one grater than other?

Comment: (T,F)  will be prioritize

Comment: Did you understand the problem? can help me find the cause

Comment: (F, F) (T, F), (F, T) order them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments order will be `(F, F) (T, F), (F, T)`

Then this should work

```
public int compare(Project o1, Project o2) {
    int result = o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    if(o1.boolean2 != o2.boolean2)return ((!o2.boolean2): 1 : -1);
    if(o1.boolean1 != o2.boolean1)return ((!o2.boolean1): 1 : -1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Your boolean pairs comparison doesn't look right. What if o1 and o2 represent same boolean pair like when `o1(F,F)` and `o2(F,F)`? In such case result of comparison should be 0 which represents equality, but your code always returns 1 or -1.

Comment: Thanks I think now it's ok, but it affects the results ?

Comment: It looks OK, and yes, it could cause problem since some sorting algorithms are able to notice that for two equal values `a` and `b` it ends up with situation where `a<b` and `b<a` which could cause throwing exception about not respecting Comparator rules/contract.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example it looks like the expected order of boolean pairs is `(F,F) < (F,T) < (T,F)`.

One way to express such order is via mapping each (boolean, boolean) pair into numeric value representing its priority/position in our order. For instance such mapping can be handled by method like:

```
//(F,F) < (F,T) < (T,F)
//  0       1       2
private static int priority(boolean b1, boolean b2){
    if (b1==false && b2==false)     return 0;
    if (b1==false && b2==true)      return 1;
    if (b1==true  && b2==false)     return 2;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("both booleans can't be true at the same time");
}
```

Then all we have to do is compare priority of boolean pairs just like we compare integers:

```
public int compare(Project o1, Project o2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int result = o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
    if (result != 0) return result;
    int priority1 = priority(o1.boolean1, o1.boolean2);
    int priority2 = priority(o2.boolean1, o2.boolean2);
    return Integer.compare(priority1, priority2);
}
```

DEMO

```
class SO61985917 {

    //(F,F) < (F,T) < (T,F)
    //  0       1       2
    private static int priority(boolean b1, boolean b2){
        if (b1==false && b2==false)     return 0;
        if (b1==false && b2==true)      return 1;
        if (b1==true  && b2==false)     return 2;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("both booleans can't be true at the same time");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        List<Project> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Project(false, false, new Date("1/1/2019"), "Jet" , "1"));
        list.add(new Project(true, false, new Date("1/1/2019"), "Sang", "2"));
        list.add(new Project(false, false, new Date("1/1/2019"), "Dung", "1"));
        list.add(new Project(false, true, new Date("1/1/2020"), "Long", "1"));
        list.add(new Project(true, false, new Date("1/1/2020"), "Nguyen", "3"));
        list.add(new Project(true, false, new Date("1/1/2020"), "Khang", "2"));

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Project>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Project o1, Project o2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int result = o1.date.compareTo(o2.date);
                if (result != 0) return result;
                int priority1 = priority(o1.boolean1, o1.boolean2);
                int priority2 = priority(o2.boolean1, o2.boolean2);
                return Integer.compare(priority1, priority2);
            }
        });

        for(Project pp : list) {
            System.out.println(pp.name);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Jet
Dung
Sang
Long
Nguyen
Khang
```

Which seems to be what you wanted since you said:

> I wan result :Jet, Dung, Sang, Long, Nguyen, Khang

Comment: Actually your solution is better in the sense OP can easily modify to his desire order.